# Angular - how to access multiple url parameters using $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, state

I have the following state in Angular routing:

```
.state("supplier/document", {
            url: "/supplier/document/:supplierid/:docid",
            controller: "ctrlSupplierDocument",
            templateUrl: "views/supplier/document.html"})
```

And I get to this state with the following code:

```
$state.go('supplier/document', { 'supplierid': $scope.supplierid, 'docid': item.QualificationID });
```

This results in me correctly going to the view in question, with a url formatted as expected:

http://localhost:60437/index.html#/supplier/document/14/70

I now need to grab the two ids from the url (14 being supplierid and 70 being the document id).  BUT $state.params is undefined (obviously it doesn't see these as GET params).  Normally, with one parameter $state.param.id works fine.  Difference here is the two parameters.

Q. How do I grab these params?  OR is there an alternative method to achieve this where I can use $state.params on the target view controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `$state.current.params.supplierid` and `$state.current.params.docid`

See: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state